# External USB Hard Drive i/o error

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive

I have an external USB hard drive that seems to  have crashed. When I plug it into any of my computers it usually will not mount. Occasionally, it does mount, but then when I run an `ls` command for instance nothing ever comes back. The drive is split into four distinct partitions, the biggest one, and the one that I would like to recover is a data partition of about 953 GB.

When I run `dmesg` (on my Ubuntu Linux system) I get these errors, the clearest of which seems to be reporting an I/O error:

```
Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 131328
[1206389.681527]  sdc: sdc1 sdc2 sdc3 sdc4
[1206389.684156] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[1206394.848541] usb 2-1.6: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[1206399.728633] usb 2-1.6: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[1206405.268562] usb 2-1.6: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[1206411.428538] usb 2-1.6: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[1206416.908592] usb 2-1.6: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[1206422.864664] usb 2-1.6: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[1206423.605712] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
[1206423.605718] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdc]  
[1206423.605720] Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
```

Does anyone know how I might go about diagnosing the problem here, and if at all possible recovering the data on this hard drive?

#### Update:

I decided to follow [these instructions](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/recover-bad-superblock-from-corrupted-partition/) about recovering a bad superblock from a corrupted drive. That involved running the command `fsck -b 32768 /dev/sdc4`. When I did that, I go the following error. I'm not sure how to answer that:

```
Data was not cleanly unmounted, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Error reading block 164867 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>?
```

When I answered yes, I just got another for the next block (164868). Is this a bad sign? Is there a next step I should take from here perhaps?

#### Update 2:

It looks to me as though the disk is really far gone. I ran ddrescue and here were the results:

```
GNU ddrescue 1.17
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
rescued:     7508 MB,  errsize:   2952 MB,  current rate:        0 B/s
   ipos:    10461 MB,   errors:      13,    average rate:     925 kB/s
   opos:    10461 MB,    time since last successful read:      46 s
Copying non-tried blocks...
ddrescue: input file disappeared: No such file or directory
```

Is this a lost cause?

Comment: Remove the case, and directly install it into your pc...

Comment: if the drive itself is going bad, I'd look into ddrescue asap before making it spin many more times.

Comment: @davidbaumann -- why is installing it directly into the pc advisable? or the right solution?

Comment: @JoeT -- i'm wondering if your recommendation is wise, just because in the [ddrescue manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html) i came across this line: "Never try to repair a file system on a drive with I/O errors; you will probably lose even more data."

Comment: There's always the chance of a broken usb controller, so testing it is never a fault.

Comment: no don't try to repair the fs, copy the data block by block to a new good HD - only if davidbaumann's suggestion does not resolve it.  and you can also combine data copy with the freezer trick as per DrMoishe Pippik's answer.  I've had to do it once and it helped.

Comment: "You should make a copy of the failing drive with ddrescue, and then try to repair the copy" https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#Examples they're telling you don't run the fs repair on the bad drive, run ddrescue instead to make a full copy, then run the repair on the good drive

Answer (score 1):

One trick that might work after you've tried all *safe* means to recover data: cool the drive and then try it again. See http://lifehacker.com/5515337/save-a-failed-hard-drive-in-your-freezer-redux.
Though I do not know what cooling does to help the drive, whether to change bearing play, change head alignment or something else entirely, it *did* help me with a drive that only clicked and would not spin up, and it worked long enough to recover data. Expect that the drive is trash after this treatment, though, good just for the rare-earth magnets inside.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't actually seen anyone getting data off with an I/O error. If your HDD doesn't have hardware encryption and has a SATA interface there might be a point in connecting it internally to the PC. Otherwise think about professional data recovery if the information is valuable.